# Is it possible to pass a database field as parameter in SQL query in SAP Crystal Report?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Is it possible to pass a database field, for example `MyTable.EmpoyeeID` as a parameter in SQL query using Command? `MyTable.EmpoyeeID` value will be defined using ASP. net.

**Sample:**

```
SELECT FName, MName, LName FROM MyTable WHERE EmpoyeeID = MyTable.EmpoyeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

option 1: yes, but you need to use aliases and, if memory serves the behavior tends to change across Crystal version.  Google the topic of Crystal Reports, SQL Expressions, and Correlated Subqueries. You should find several in-depth threads.

option 2: use a 3rd-party UFL (User Function Library) that allows you to call arbitrary SQL statement you create inside a Crystal formula (not just SELECT statements are supported using that approach).